# Using Enum for factory in Java, a best practice?

Tags: java, enums, factory

Java allow us to embed data and behaviour on Enum.
I don't want to implement a factory directly on an Enum, because I think this is not its role.

But I can put class reference on the enum, and contruct object on an external factory. Comparing to a traditionnal factory pattern, what is the best implementation for you ? Which solution is better to use in which case ?

Now, the code.

Function used in both solutions to construct objects.  Usefull to implement fly-weight pattern with a Map if required.

```
private Action getAction(Class<? extends Action> actionClazz) {
    // logger + error handling
    return actionClazz.newInstance();
}
```

1) With a traditionnal factory:

```
public enum ActionEnum {
    LOAD_DATA,
    LOAD_CONFIG;
}

public Action getAction(ActionEnum action) {
    switch (action) {
    case LOAD_CONFIG:
        return getAction(ActionLoadConfig.class);
    case LOAD_DATA:
        return getAction(ActionLoadData.class);
    }
}
```

2) With Enum-styled factory :

```
public enum ActionEnum {
    LOAD_DATA(ActionLoadConfig.class),
    LOAD_CONFIG(ActionLoadData.class);

    public ActionEnum(Class<? extends Action> clazz){...}
    public Class<? extends Action> getClazz() {return this.clazz}
}

public Action getAction(ActionEnum action) {
    return getAction(action.getClazz());
}
```

Comment: can you give me an example of the second one in a main function? (I wanna see the usage of this factory), this question is for 4 years ago, still is it the best way ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The second one is much cleaner: it doesn't need any long switch block, and has 0 risk of forgetting one of the enum values like the first one has.

It's not always possible to use it, though, because the enum might be some generic enum (`Month`, for example), that should not be coupled to the factory of actions.

Answer (score 21):

This works for me:

```
 enum ActionEnum
    {
      LOAD_DATA {

        @Override
        public ActionLoadData getInstance() {
            return new ActionLoadData ();
        }

    },
    LOAD_CONFIG {

        @Override
        public ActionLoadConfig getInstance() {
            return new ActionLoadConfig();
        }

    };

    public abstract ILightBulb getInstance();
}

class ActionFactory
{
    public  Action getAction(ActionEnum action)
    {
       return action.getInstance();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a very elegant solution. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 20):

IMO calling `newInstance()` should be avoided if at all possible, as it blatantly defeats some of the compile time protection given by java (read its javadoc) and introduces new `Exception`s to handle.

Here's a solution similar to [what Sergey provided](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17581310/using-enum-for-factory-in-java-a-best-practice/41281789#41281789), just a little more concise thanks to functional interfaces and method references.

```
public enum ActionEnum {
  LOAD_DATA(ActionLoadData::new),
  LOAD_CONFIG(ActionLoadConfig::new)

  private Supplier<Action> instantiator;

  public Action getInstance() {
    return instantiator.get();
  }

  ActionEnum(Supplier<Action> instantiator) {
    this.instantiator = instantiator;
  }
}

public Action getAction(ActionEnum action) {
  return action.getInstance();
}
```

Comment: This is a very elegant solution. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 8):

To decouple even more:

```
static final EnumMap<ActionEnum, Class<? extends Action>> enumToClass = new EnumMap<>();
static
{  
    enumToClass.put(ActionEnum.LOAD_DATA, ActionLoadData.class);
    etc...
}


public Action getAction(ActionEnum action) 
{
    return getAction(enumToClass.get(action));
}
```

`EnumMap` is very fast so no worries.